# HNS failed with error : The parameter is incorrect

Tags: docker, docker-compose, windows-container

I am making a docker containerized application using visual studio 2017.
When running docker through visual studio first, I got an error that "ERROR: client version 1.22 is too old".

This error was resolved by updating docker compose to version 2.1

Below link contains further instruction about this specific error

[ERROR: client version 1.22 is too old](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4106#issuecomment-266105765)

After this error was resolved ,On Building docker now I get "HNS failed with error : The parameter is incorrect."

From multiple github discussion I have found that it is a windows network error.

Is there a solution to this problem ?
Should I down grade docker version or install something else.

I am using windows container.
On running docker version
Client:
 Version:      17.06.0-ce
 API version:  1.30
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   02c1d87
 Built:        Fri Jun 23 21:30:30 2017
 OS/Arch:      windows/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.06.0-ce
 API version:  1.30 (minimum version 1.24)
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   02c1d87
 Built:        Fri Jun 23 22:19:00 2017
 OS/Arch:      windows/amd64
 Experimental: true

Edit:

If I switch to linux container this problem is solved.
But another issue occurs drive is not shared.
After sharing d: drive drive sharing issue still occurs.

How can I resolve linux container drive sharing issue.

I want to use windows container locally so that I can deploy this app on azure.

Comment: Try to clean your docker network stack (https://github.com/Microsoft/Virtualization-Documentation/tree/master/windows-server-container-tools/CleanupContainerHostNetworking)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This is a known limitation. At present windows only supports one NAT network. Removing Netnat by invoke Remove-Netnat is not supported.

Run this in powerhell.

`Get-NetNat | Remove-NetNat`

Comment: Hello, I'm using these comands and run docker-compose up -d nginx and return error:

ERROR: Network "laradock_default" needs to be recreated - option "com.docker.network.windowsshim.hnsid" has changed

Comment: Search laradock github repository for similar issues. You might find an answer.

Comment: Just in case if anyone needs to follow up on this issue https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/598

Answer (score 6):

To prevent docker-compose from creating a new **default** network you can use the existing  one by specifying it in docker-compose.yml:

```
networks:
    default:
        external:
            name: nat
```

To check for existing networks execute

```
docker network ls
```

Answer (score 0):

Open the powershell(X64) in admin mode
Execute below command

```
Get-NetNat
```

If it returns something like this

[image]

Then run below command in powershell

```
Remove-NetNat
```