# How to get Docker Compose running on Windows Server 2016

Tags: powershell, docker-compose, windows-server-2016

My goal is to deploy a docker-compose solution to a server running Windows server 2016.  I'm able to install everything but when I run a basic compose example I get an error:

```
Creating network "composetest_default" with the default driver
ERROR: HNS failed with error : The parameter is incorrect.
```

This is the example I'm following:
https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/

I was running a more advanced docker-compose file that used Postgres, PGAdmin and a python build but was getting similar networking errors.  So my question is, how do I resolve these networking errors?

I've tried running on Windows Containers.  I've tried running on Linux Containers and setting up Hyper-V to run correctly `Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V -All`.  I've tried specifying the default network:

```
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: nat
```

I've tried removing the NetNat network that's specified in this post [HNS failed with error : The parameter is incorrect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45394360/hns-failed-with-error-the-parameter-is-incorrect). `Get-NetNat | Remove-NetNat`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was running Windows Server on a GCP Compute instance and GCP does not support Hyper-V.  I think this was the root of all my problems.  Reference:
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/enable-nested-virtualization-vm-instances